# Why is it not possible to update a django model instance like this: instance(**update_dict)?

Tags: python, django, model

I can make a new django model object with `Model(**dictionary)` but if I want to update an instance in the same way, I've found only `update_or_create` which has its problems and often returns 'duplicate PK' errors. It also doesn't seem particularly pythonic to call a custom helper function on a model object. Alternatively, you can use this pattern:

```
 Model.objects.get(id=id).update(**dict)
```

or

```
model.__dict__.update(**dict)
model.save()
```

The latter feels like a hack and I read a few times that it's not 'supposed' to be done this way. The first method requires a query call and again feels incorrect since the model instance is likely already instantiated and to update it we need to send a query to the DB again?

I also read that 'you can do this with a form' - but its not always users that are updating models in the DB, there are all kinds of functions we might write which requires models to be updated. I wonder, is there a reason that the below code is not possible/implemented? Is there a reason that model objects are not directly callable and updateable in this way?

```
model_instance(**dict)
model_instance.save()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[**Model instances** [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/) do not have any built-in methods which update the field values by feeding in keyword arguments.

### Queryset `update()`

The following query will update the database row immediately, but has the disadvantage that it [won't call any pre-save or post-save signals [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update) that you may have registered to the model:

```py
Model.objects.filter(id=model_instance.id).update(**dict_)
```

And as you mentioned, if you intend to keep using the same instance you would need to update its values from the database:

```py
model_instance.refresh_from_db()
```

### Why `model_instance(**dict_)` doesn't work

Django model instances (objects) are not callable. Objects cannot be called like functions by default. For example, when you create a plain dict `dict_ = dict()`, you can't update it by calling `dict_(**kwargs)`. An object can be *made* callable by overriding the [`__call__` [Python docs]](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) class method.

### A solution – custom `update()` method on model

You could create your own model method so you're only making one database call (and preserving signals). For example you could create an [abstract base class [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) that all of your models inherit from (rather than from `models.Model`) e.g.

```py
class ModelWithUpdate(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def update(self, commit=False, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)
        if commit:
            self.save()
```

And then your usage would be:

```py
model_instance.update(**dict_)
model_instance.save()

# or a shortcut
model_instance.update(commit=True, **dict_)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just:

```
Model.objects.filter(id=id).update(**kwargs)
```